# Strong convergence of an "averaging" operator

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be an Hilbert space and $S:X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear operator with $||S||=1 
$

Define $$T_n= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} S^r$$

I want to show it converges strongly to some bounded operator $T$ and to identify it.

I have showed that $T_n x$ has a limit in $X$ for $x\in \ker(I-S) + \operatorname{ran}(I-S)$
and that $||T_n||$ is uniformly bounded.

Hence I just need to show that $\ker(I-S) + \operatorname{ran}(I-S)$ is a dense subspace of $X$

If I can prove $\ker(I-S^*)=\ker(I-S)$ then I could conclude how can I prove this?

I also need to identify the limit: as Joel noted in the comments, by Mean Ergodic Theorem, the limit is a projection on $X$ onto $\ker (I-S)$ there should a direct way of proving this though, without appealing to the Mean Ergodic Theorem.

After help from T.A.E. we concluded that the only remaining issue is to prove that, for this $S$, $\ker(I-S^*)=\ker(I-S)$.

Just for reference (and to understand how the problem develops) it is from a past exam question: https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/b04b-12.pdf 
question 1.

Comment: The limit is in general not $S$. Consider $S(x) = -x$, then the limit is $0$ (even in the operator norm).

Comment: What you are asking about is very close to the Mean Ergodic Theorem, with the adjustment that $S$ is unitary. The limiting operator is a projection operator onto the space $ker(I-S)$.

Comment: @Joel Thanks! I looked it up and it is indeed what my problem is about. The proof of that theorem seems pretty non trivial, and since this was set as the last part of an exam question (on a course that did not cover such theorem) I think there should be an easy way to prove it in this case!

Comment: See Theorem 3 here: http://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/advanced-analyis-notes-5-hilbert-spaces-application-von-neumanns-mean-ergodic-theorem/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{D}(T)$ be the set of vectors $x$ for which the limit $\lim_{n}T_{n}x$ exists, and let $Tx$ denote that limit. It's not hard to verify that $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is a linear space and that $T$ is linear on its domain. $T$ is bounded on its domain with $\|Tx\|\le \|x\|$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$ because $\|T_{n}\| \le 1$ for all $n$.

The domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is closed. To see this, let $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)^{c}$. Because $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)^{c}$, then, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x_{\epsilon} \in \mathcal{D}(T)$ such that $\|x-x_{\epsilon}\| < \epsilon/3$; for this fixed $\epsilon$ we may then choose $N$ such that $\|T_{n}x_{\epsilon}-T_{m}x_{\epsilon}\|<\epsilon/3$ whenever $n,m \ge N$. It follows that, for $n,m \ge N$,
$$
\begin{align}
    \|T_{n}x-T_{m}x\| & \le\|T_{n}(x-x_{\epsilon})\|
            +\|T_{n}x_{\epsilon}-T_{m}x_{\epsilon}\|+\|T_{m}(x-x_{\epsilon})\| \\
      & < \|x-x_{\epsilon}\|+\epsilon/3+\|x-x_{\epsilon}\| < \epsilon.
\end{align}
$$
Consequently $\{ T_{n}x\}$ converges for $x \in \mathcal{D}(T)^{c}$, which proves that $\mathcal{D}(T)=\mathcal{D}(T)^{c}$.

It is easy to verify that $(I-S)T_{n}=T_{n}(I-S)=\frac{1}{n}(S^{n}-I)$, which converges to $0$ in $\mathcal{L}(X)$. If $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$, then $(I-S)x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$ and $(I-S)Tx=T(I-S)x=0$. So $S$ maps $\mathcal{D}(T)$ into itself, and
$$
                                  STx=TSx = Tx,\;\;\; x \in \mathcal{D}(T).
$$
Using this, $T_{n}T=T$ on $\mathcal{D}(T)$, which further shows that $T$ maps $\mathcal{D}(T)$ into itself, with
$$
                                   T^{2}x=Tx,\;\;\; x \in \mathcal{D}(T).
$$
So $T$ is a projection on its domain. $T=0$ on $\mathcal{R}(I-S)^{c}$; and $T=1$ on $\mathcal{N}(I-S)$ because $T_{n}x=x$ for $x\in\mathcal{N}(I-S)$.

If the range of $I-S$ is dense in $X$, then $\mathcal{D}(T)=X$. I don't see how to take the domain issue any further than
$$
                 (\mathcal{N}(I-S)+ \mathcal{R}(I-S))^{c}\subseteq\mathcal{D}(T).
$$
**New Addition:** If $S^{\star}x=x$ and $x\ne 0$, then
$$
        (Tx,x) = \lim_{n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(x,(S^{\star})^{r}x)=(x,x).
$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
          (x,x)=(Tx,x)=|(Tx,x)|\le \|Tx\|\|x\| \le \|x\|^{2}.
$$
So you have equality for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Since $Tx \ne 0$ is implied, then there exists $\lambda$ such that $Tx=\lambda x$ because $\{ Tx,x\}$ must be a linearly-dependent set of vectors. Then $(x,x)=(Tx,x)=\lambda(x,x)$ gives $\lambda=1$, which implies that $T=I$ on $\mathcal{N}(I-S^{\star})=\mathcal{R}(I-S)^{\perp}$. We already knew that $T=0$ on $\mathcal{R}(I-S)^{c}$. So $T$ is determined on
$$
        X=\mathcal{R}(I-S)^{c}\oplus\mathcal{R}(I-S)^{\perp}=\mathcal{R}(I-S)^{c}\oplus\mathcal{N}(I-S^{\star}).
$$
It appears that $T$ must be the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{N}(I-S^{\star})$.

I think you can apply the same analysis again after replacing replacing $S$ by $S^{\star}$ and obtaining a corresponding $T'$. It would follow that $T'=T^{\star}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{N}(I-S^{\star\star})=\mathcal{N}(I-S)$.
However $T^{\star}=T$ is an orthogonal projection, which means that $\mathcal{N}(I-S)=\mathcal{N}(I-S^{\star})$. I'm assuming $\mathcal{D}(T')=X$ again. That's a point that apparently can be proved according to the problem statement in your PDF.

Comment: thanks for the good answer, I had done some of the things you mentioned in your answer, what I am still not sure about is how I can prove that $\ker(I-S)= \ker(I-S^*)$ any idea ?

Comment: This would not be true in general. Do you have a reason to believe that it is true in this particular case if $\mathcal{D}(T)=X$?

Comment: It is what an exam question asks to prove, so I think it should be true: take a look here https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/b04b-12.pdf the end of the first question!

Comment: Okay, so I ended up following their plan without knowing about this exam problem. I showed (a) (b) by showing that the domain of $T$ is a closed subspace. I showed (i) and (ii). Property (iii) is a general fact. So, what remains is item (iv). I think I was correct that we could not say anything more about the domain in general. That appears correct, because they ask you to show (iv) based on the assumption that $\mathcal{D}(T)=X$. The hint is Cauchy-Schwarz, which is interesting. hmmmm...

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have made it more explicit where my confusion was from! I've been thinking about this for two days now...what is strange is that students are supposed to solve the entire problem in 45 minutes! it should be easy enough...

Comment: I was talking to a professor who had been asked to send a letter recommending a student to Oxford. He said, "I don't want to do that. They wouldn't have me at Oxford. I'm afraid they'll grade my letter and send it back." Hehe.

Comment: I have to take that exam in 3 days! They really like grading things here though, the prof is rightly scared :D

Comment: I think I see their hint, or at least the first step in using it, but I don't trust the result. Take at look at what I added. Aside: If you're feeling a little uneasy, remember that they chose to you to be there, and Oxford doesn't make mistakes. :)

Comment: Take a look at the new edit.