# weak operator closure of $K$ equals to the strong operator closure

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

It is well-known that if $K$ is a convex set of $B(H)$, then the weak operator closure of $K$ equals to the strong operator closure of $K$. [see e.g. Conway Chapter IX, Cor 5.2, A course in Functional analysis]

However, let $U$ be a shift operator on $H=\ell^2$ and  $K=conv\{U^k, k\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Consider the WOT closure and SOT closure of $K$. It is clear that $0\in \bar{K}^{wo}$ as $U^k \rightarrow_{wo} 0$. But I don't know how to construct a net of $K$ tending to $0$ in SOT.

Comment: And what about convexity?

Comment: @TrialAndError conv is the convex hull. Could u give me a specific net tending to 0 in SOT？

Comment: Aha, i got it. Using convexity is ok by noting that Hilbert is strictly convex.

Comment: There is an optimistic choice for such a net.  Take $K_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n U^k$.  You can check that this converges strongly to 0 or you can use a result like the one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829527/strong-convergence-of-an-averaging-operator?rq=1

Comment: @JoshKeneda  I got it. THX, MAN